# Error de duplicacion de array en un bucle for java

Tags: java, array

Ejercicio : Lo que debe de hacer
Crea un programa para llevar el control de los artículos de un almacén. De cada artículo se debe saber el código, la descripción,
el precio de compra, el precio de venta y el stock (número de unidades). El menú del programa debe tener las siguientes opciones:

```
1. Listado de artículos (código, descripción, precio compra, precio venta, stock)

2. Alta de un nuevo artículo (se deberá comprobar que no existe un artículo ya con el mismo código)

3. Baja de un artículo existente

4. Modificación de un artículo existente

5. Entrada de mercancía (aumentar  stock de un artículo)

6. Salida  de mercancía (disminuir stock de un artículo)

7. Salir

La entrada y salida de mercancía supone respectivamente el incremento y decremento de stock de un determinado artículo.

Hay que controlar que no se pueda sacar más mercancía de la que hay en el almacén.

Se supone que hay un máximo de 100 artículos distintos.

Se deberá entregar un sólo fichero comprimido con todos los ficheros .java (sólo éstos) que compongan la aplicación.
```

Enlace del anterior cuestión : [Problema con la búsqueda de elementos de un array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/382548/problema-con-la-b%c3%basqueda-de-elementos-de-un-array)

Código fuente : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zVpRyEszoNvFpk85uXvwo5Vt8Fgnp7gk/view?usp=sharing

Salida

resulta que la segunda pasada del bucle lo que hace es que si escribo el primer código eso funciona pero al llegar a escribir el segundo código me pide que lo meta dos veces y el tercero 3 veces, y así  repitiendo una y otra vez cada vez que se mete un código nuevo como se ve en la imagen el resultado del Ouput lo subrayado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte de añadir
`
public void añadirElemento() {

```
    Scanner teclado1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner teclado3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner teclado4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner teclado5 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner teclado0 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] añadir  = new String[100];
    Double[] añadir1 = new Double[100];
    Double[] añadir2 = new Double[100];
    Integer[] añadir0 = new Integer[100];
    Integer[] añadir3 = new Integer[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < nombre.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" El codigo Nuevo Producto : ");
        añadir0[i] = teclado0.nextInt();
        
        if (Objects.equals(codigo[i], añadir0[i])) {
            System.out.print(" El codigo ya existe");
            break;
        }
        if (codigo[i] == null) {

            codigo[i] = añadir0[i];
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print(" Nombre del Nuevo Producto : ");
            añadir[i] = teclado1.nextLine();
            nombre[i] = añadir[i];
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print(" Precio de Compra del Producto nuevo : ");
            añadir1[i] = teclado3.nextDouble();
            precioCompra[i] = añadir1[i];
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print(" Precio de Venta del Producto nuevo : ");
            añadir2[i] = teclado4.nextDouble();
            precioVenta[i] = añadir2[i];
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print(" Stock del nuevo Producto : ");
            añadir3[i] = teclado5.nextInt();
            stock[i] = añadir3[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Por favor leer [mcve]. Colocar *todo* tu programa es contraproducente. Lo ideal es que coloques una pequeña parte que permita reproducir tu problema. Si no eres capaz de colocar una parte para reproducirlo, entonces tal vez necesites modularizar un poco más el mismo. Saludos

Comment: Mauricio Contreras listo puse el código breve-mente para que sea mas facil

Comment: ¿No necesitas tantos `Scanner`, o si? Pides el código del producto dentro de un ciclo, por tanto te lo va a pedir tantas veces como iteraciones haga el ciclo. ¿En realidad es necesaria la imagen?

Comment: la imegen es para que vea lo que imprime y en cuanto lo scanner se lo tengo que cambiar

Comment: Hola amigo ya edité la respuesta puedes probar el código que te dejo y me cuentas si te funciona

Comment: vale muchas gracias cheox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo tu problema se debe a que el array codigo (y todos los demás) queda cargado con los códigos que digitaste previamente y cuando haces la validación con tu while:

```
while (codigo[i] == null) {

}
```

en ese momento el valor de codigo[i] no es null entones salta diretamente a la linea

```
else {

                break;

            }
```

y así va a continuar hasta que  encuentre un valor nulo en el la posicion i del array

Para que puedas observar el error puedes imprimir el valor de codigo[i] cada que vez llamas al metodo añadirElemento().

puedes corregirlo agregando un for para recorrer todos los elementos del array para buscar si  el codigo ya se encuentra registrado. Si no hay código registrado  entonces buscamos  la siguiente posición null  y asignamos el valor de j a la variable i. Puedes probar este código

```
 public void añadirElemento() {
            
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner teclado1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner teclado3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner teclado4 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner teclado5 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner teclado0 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String añadir, pre;
    
            Double añadir1,
                    añadir2;
    
            Integer añadir0,
                    añadir3,
                    añadir4;
           
      public void añadirElemento() {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner teclado1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner teclado3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner teclado4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner teclado5 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner teclado0 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String añadir, pre;

        Double añadir1,
                añadir2;

        Integer añadir0,
                añadir3,
                añadir4;

        for (int i = 0; i < nombre.length; i++) {

            System.out.print(" Deseas Continuar S/N : ");

            pre = teclado2.next();

            if (pre.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
                System.out.print(" El codigo Nuevo Producto : ");
                añadir0 = teclado0.nextInt();

                for (int j = 0; j < nombre.length ; j++) {
                    if (Objects.equals(codigo[j], añadir0)) {
                        System.out.print(" El codigo ya existe");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (codigo[j] == null) {
                        i = j;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                codigo[i] = añadir0;

                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.print(" Nombre del Nuevo Producto : ");
                añadir = teclado1.nextLine();
                nombre[i] = añadir;

                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.print(" Precio de Compra del Producto nuevo : ");
                añadir1 = teclado3.nextDouble();
                precioCompra[i] = añadir1;

                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.print(" Precio de Venta del Producto nuevo : ");
                añadir2 = teclado4.nextDouble();
                precioVenta[i] = añadir2;

                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.print(" Stock del nuevo Producto : ");
                añadir3 = teclado5.nextInt();
                stock[i] = añadir3;

            } else {

                break;

            }
        }

    }
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: vale muchas gracias lo voy a mirrar

Comment: lo he estado mirando y si hago eso resulta que no para de pedirme que introduzca el código y una y otra vez y lo que quiero es meter productos por ejemplo : hoy me llega dos producto los añado esos dos , que mañana me llega uno nuevo pues que se introduzca después de esos dos códigos

Comment: hola buenas muchas gracias ahora si que hace lo que debe :)

Comment: e incluso gracia a tu codigo pude terminar los demas fijandome del error

Comment: toma aqui tienes el codigo completo por si lo quieres : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bvj1_aY4xdGVFKNjcBEo0v6VBNEIW3JD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Me alegro que te funcionara :)

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que te recomendaria es que solo tengas un escaner el cual sea global con lo cual te ahorraras muchas lineas de codigo

Otra es que cuando sean enteros los que vas a leer los guardes en un una variable simple en lugar de un array ya que el array una vez declarado consume memoria y es mas mas comodo para el tipo de proceso que estas haciendo trabajarlo de ese modo y no solo con enteros, si no con todos los tipos de datos a menos que realmente necesites un array para trabajar...

Respondiendo Tu pregunta
Supongo que quieres que te solicite los datos del porducto ya que veo no lo esta haciendo

podrias intentar manejarlo con banderas y con un segundo for dentro del primero para hacer tu verificacion o con un ciclo while el cual podria ser algo asi

```
//En este caso cambiare tu Integer[] añadir0 = new Integer[100];
//por una variable la cual no sera un array asi que ahora la variabe solo seria
//añadir0 y sera con la que trabajaremos en la lectura  



int j=0, b=0;
while(numeros[j] != null ){
    if(numeros[j] == añadir0){
       b=1; //Activamos la bandera pues el codigo ya existe
    }         
}

//una vez que tengamos la verificacion realizada para que se decida si introducimo
//o no datos el if seria así

if (b==0) {
        codigo[i] = añadir0[i];
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print(" Nombre del Nuevo Producto : ");
        añadir[i] = teclado1.nextLine();
        nombre[i] = añadir[i];
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print(" Precio de Compra del Producto nuevo : ");
        añadir1[i] = teclado1.nextDouble();
        precioCompra[i] = añadir1[i];
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print(" Precio de Venta del Producto nuevo : ");
        añadir2[i] = teclado1.nextDouble();
        precioVenta[i] = añadir2[i];
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print(" Stock del nuevo Producto : ");
        añadir3[i] = teclado1.nextInt();
        stock[i] = añadir3[i];
    }

    //Quitamos el break ya que si dejamos este rompemos el for y ya 
    //esto hace que no se repita nuevamente
```

Ahora bien no se si ya haz hecho uso de objetos pero podrias crear un objeto llamado producto y en el cual tendras los atributos para el mismo

Suerte...

Comment: muchas gracias lo voy a mirrar ahora mismo

Comment: yo necesito un array por lo que pone en mi ejercicio

Comment: 1. Listado de artículos (código, descripción, precio compra, precio venta, stock)
    2. Alta de un nuevo artículo (se deberá comprobar que no existe un artículo ya con el mismo código)
    3. Baja de un artículo existente
    4. Modificación de un artículo existente
    5. Entrada de mercancía (aumentar  stock de un artículo)
    6. Salida  de mercancía (disminuir stock de un artículo)
    7. Salir

Comment: Crea un programa para llevar el control de los artículos de un almacén. De cada artículo se debe saber el código, la descripción,
    el precio de compra, el precio de venta y el stock (número de unidades). El menú del programa debe tener las siguientes opciones:

Comment: La entrada y salida de mercancía supone respectivamente el incremento y decremento de stock de un determinado artículo.
    Hay que controlar que no se pueda sacar más mercancía de la que hay en el almacén.
    Se supone que hay un máximo de 100 artículos distintos.
    Se deberá entregar un sólo fichero comprimido con todos los ficheros .java (sólo éstos) que compongan la aplicación.